# PHP sorting by column header issue

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, html-table

I am having an issue sorting my datatable by the column header.

I have a build-query mechanism on my site that can take in 1 or more values the user selects.  The values get turned into PHP variables that then get passed into the query and prints out the datatable to the screen.  The address bar URL is updated as well.

I want to be able to sort by the column headers of the table.

I will show you the PHP code bypassing the whole build-query function.  I'll start right at the SORT portion and the query:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['sort'] == "") {
 $sort_by = "BOL_NUMBER";
} else {
 $sort_by = $_GET['sort'];
}

$select = "";

if ($_SESSION['where'] != "")  {
  $select = "SELECT * FROM `mainTable` WHERE (". $_SESSION['where'] . ") ORDER BY " . $sort_by . "";
}  

// $_SESSION['where'] comes from the build query and can contain 1 or more values

$QueryResult = mysql_query($select) or die ();
$resnum = mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);
```

This next part is where the table gets populated:

```
if ($resnum == 0) {
  echo "no results";
} else {

echo "<table>\n";
echo "<thead><tr>" .
"<th>BOL</th>" .
"<th>CONTAINER</th>" .
"<th>LOCATION</th>" .
"<th>STATUS</th>" .
"</tr></thead><tbody>\n";

while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[BOL_NUMBER]}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[CONTAINER_NUMBER]}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[LOCATION_CITY]}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row[STATUS_TYPE]}</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>\n";

?>
```

There are many more columns.  I just picked a couple.

I found this page for this next part:

[Sorting html table with a href and php from sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705530/sorting-html-table-with-a-href-and-php-from-sql-database)

So I tried to apply what I read in the link to the headers, like this:

```
 "<th><a href='myPage.php?sort=BOL_NUMBER'>BOL</a></th>" .
 "<th><a href='myPage.php?sort=CONTAINER_NUMBER'>CONTAINER</a></th>" .
 "<th><a href='myPage.php?sort=LOCATION_CITY'>LOCATION</a></th>" .
 "<th><a href='myPage.php?sort=STATUS_TYPE'>STATUS</a></th>" .
```

Now, I can click on the column headers, but when I do, it does not keep the user's selection and I can tell because the URL changes like this example below:

(this is just an example.  it does not include the parameters in the table above)
(just keep note of the &sort in this url)

```
 http://home.someCompany.com/myAPP/mypage.php?direction=I&type=&submit=Go&city=&pod=&terminal=&ramp=&container=&bol=&voyage=&conStatus=&con_location=&sort=&status=
```

Will change to this (if I select the header for CONTAINER):

```
 http://home.someCompany.com/myAPP/mypage.php?&sort=CONTAINER_NUMBER
```

When this happens, the datatable is no longer on the screen.  It's like it removes everything from the query and just adds the sort.  But there is now nothing to sort.

Comment: Why do this with a database sort? Try using the plethora of JS based table sorting plugins (for example http://tablesorter.com/)

Comment: One solution is to keep all the other parameters in session variables. Another way is to have the PHP construct a full URL for the column headings, by merging the `sort` options in with all the `$_GET` query parameters it received. The `http_build_query` function is useful for this.

Comment: It should also be noted that you are passing raw data into mysql_query (which extremely dangerous) opening you up to injection attacks and more.  You should in the very least escape the injected parameters ($_GET) or switch to a non-deprecated database library like PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: @drmarvelous, I am indeed using mysql_real_escape_string up in the build-query mechanism.  I just didn't display it.

Comment: @drmarvelous, I am looking at tablesorter.com.  Will I have to change much of my existing code to be able to use tablesorter.com?

Comment: You will have to remove a lot of code, but that's about it.  Let it handle all of the sorting itself.  Just implement one of their examples and load your data the same way you are loading it now.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` superglobal variable give you access to the `GET` parameters. By using it you can keep the current parameters of the request.

So by changing your link by this :

```
$urlQuery = str_replace(array('&sort=BOL_NUMBER', '&sort=CONTAINER_NUMBER', '&sort=LOCATION_CITY', '&sort=STATUS_TYPE'), '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); // To clean previous sorting, maybe replace by a regex

"<th><a href='myPage.php?' . $urlQuery  . '&sort=BOL_NUMBER'>BOL</a></th>" .
"<th><a href='myPage.php?' . $urlQuery  . '&sort=CONTAINER_NUMBER'>CONTAINER</a></th>" .
"<th><a href='myPage.php?' . $urlQuery  . '&sort=LOCATION_CITY'>LOCATION</a></th>" .
"<th><a href='myPage.php?' . $urlQuery  . '&sort=STATUS_TYPE'>STATUS</a></th>" .
```

You should reach your goal.